# php_info() not effect when edit value in php.ini on nginx webserver

Tags: php, nginx

I've already installed php, fcgi, nginx, the system running as no problem, but the problem happen when:

1. I update memory_limit in php.ini, then restart php-cgi, nginx, but when use phpinfo, theo memory_limit is not effected.
2. I install 2 new extensions: curl and memcache, add 2 lines: extension=curl.so and extension=memcache.so, restart php-cgi and nginx, phpinfo also not show up the value curl and memcache in phpinfo.

So, how would i do?Please help me.

Answer (score -1):

If you have the output of `phpinfo()` available you can see what configuration file is actually loaded.

There can be various ways and locations a php-settings-file may be located, see 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php

Ah, yes, and this is stackoverflow, not serverfault.